# how can store the number 100 only when 1 to 99 numbers are must have inside the db

Tags: django-rest-framework

**suppose i am adding matchround_5, round 1,2,3,4 must have inside the db ,check each round are present in the database , How can i solve this issue?**

> Modelserializer

```
class MatchScoreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

def create(self, validated_data):
    gameevent = validated_data.get('gameevent')
    match_round =validated_data.get('match_round')
    match = Matchscore.objects.filter(gameevent=gameevent,match_round=match_round).first()
    if match :
        validated_data = Matchscore.objects.filter(gameevent=gameevent,match_round=match_round).update(**validated_data)
        match.refresh_from_db()
        return validated_data
    else:
        return Matchscore.objects.create(**validated_data)
       
    
def validate(self, validated_data):
    gameevent = validated_data.get('gameevent')
    match_round =validated_data.get('match_round')
    if not match_round :
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Enter value more than 0")
    if match_round == 1:
        return validated_data
    round = range(1,match_round)
    match = Matchscore.objects.filter(gameevent=gameevent,match_round__in=round).values_list('match_round',flat=True)
    match = set(match)
    if match :
        return validated_data
    if len(match)== match_round-1:
        return validated_data
    else:
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Enter a valid match_round")
```

> Here my model

```
class Matchscore(TimeStampedModel):
gameevent = models.ForeignKey(GameEvent, null=True, related_name='game_event',on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
match_round = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
team_a = models.ForeignKey(Team,null=True,related_name='team_one',on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
team_a_score = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
team_b = models.ForeignKey(Team,null=True,related_name='team_two',on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
team_b_score = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
team_won = models.ForeignKey(Team,null=True,related_name='team', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

Comment: how can i add round 3 only after by addming of round 2, please give any solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking `if match` to return the validated data is not sufficient. You should check the length. You thus return the validated data if `len(match) == match_round - 1`.

You can however let the database return the number of distinct values, and thus avoid counting yourself:

```
matches = Matchscore.objects.filter(
    gameevent=gameevent,
    match_round__range=(1, match_round)
).values('match_round').distinct().count()

if matches == match_round-1:
    return validated_data
else:
    raise serializers.ValidationError('Enter a valid match_round')
```